# Returning arrays in C instead of switch statements, nested set of values

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, switch-statement

```
int* path = malloc(sizeof(int)*4));

switch(one) {
    case NORTH:
        switch(two) {
            case NORTH:
                memcpy(path, ((int[4]){7, 8, 9, 10}), sizeof(int)*4);
                break;
            case WEST:
                memcpy(path, ((int[4]){9, 10, 11, 12}), sizeof(int)*4);
                break;
            case SOUTH:
                memcpy(path, ((int[4]){1, 2, 3, 4}), sizeof(int)*4);
                break;
            case EAST:
                memcpy(path, ((int[4]){7, 8, 9, 10}), sizeof(int)*4);
                break;
            case MAX_DIRECTION:
                return NULL;
        }
    case WEST:
        switch(two) {
            case NORTH:
                memcpy(path, ((int[4]){7, 8, 9, 10}), sizeof(int)*4);
                break;
            case WEST:
                memcpy(path, ((int[4]){1, 2, 2, 3}), sizeof(int)*4);
            ...
    ...
return path
```

And so on for this example for each case of NORTH, WEST, SOUTH, EAST. Idea being you would pass in one and two into the function and it would return an integer array cooresponding to the right value ex. [NORTH][WEST] = [9, 10, 11, 12]. 
For conciseness, I defined NORTH down to EAST, as 0-3 respectively.

My idea is to instead have it as multi-dimensonal array.
For example a user would pass in 0,1. It'd access the first array cooresponding to 0 (NORTH), then it'd access the second array cooresponding to 1 (WEST), and return the desired array.

I've tried a couple of things but the only thing that immediately made sense to me was declaring and then assigning each index of the array one by one. Not sure how to do it all at once and accomplish what I want.

Would very much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a 3 dimensional array.  The first two dimensions correspond to the values of `one` and `two`, while the third is the array of numbers you want to return.

You can declare the array like this:

```
int arr[4][4][4] = {
    { {7, 8, 9, 10}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {7, 8, 9, 10} },
    { {7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {8, 9, 10, 11} },
    { {7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {8, 9, 10, 11} },
    { {7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {8, 9, 10, 11} }
};
```

And get the proper subarray like this:

```
int *path = arr[one][two];
```

Comment: Would I be able to return that from a function and be able to access the subarray without issue? Because I believe I would have to malloc but not sure about mallocing while also declaring the same way.

Comment: No need to allocate dynamically.  Declare the array as `static` so that its lifetime exists outside the function, or declare it at file scope.

Comment: It depends on your usage of the array after you return it from that function. If the caller might change it, you need to malloc+copy it.

Comment: Just to confirm, are they any drawbacks to declaring an array as static? Granted this will be the only static variable I declare in my program but are there any disadvantages in terms of used memory I guess (and other potential downsides)?

Comment: Assuming you don't expect the array to be modified, there's no issue.  In fact, you may also want to declare it `const` if that's the case.